# regex to validate consecutive punctuation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I want to validate the value of a textbox with Regular Expressions in jQuery. i.e. it will detect the consecutive punctuation marks. What will be the regex string for this requirement?

If I type `fahad''s`, it should give me an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it here: https://regex101.com/r/Q4KKmy/1

```
\W\W+
```

Matches anything other than a letter, digit or underscore, that occurs 2+ times sequentially.

If you want only punctuation you can choose a range of characters, for example only . ' , :

```
[\.',][\.',]+
```

Some results:

```
fahad''s
fahad'''''''s
fahad....'s
```

And 0 results:

```
fahad.s
fah.ad.s
```